# Interpolate ruby if statement in haml javascript block

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

This is the code I currently have:

```
:javascript
    // do something
- if current_user.role? :client
    :javascript
        //do something else
```

It's obviously not very clean since I'm repeating the :javascript haml filter. I'd like to avoid that, but I don't know how to properly write a Ruby "if" statement inside a HAML :javascript block.

I know how to interpolate variables with #{}, but how do you do the same for whole if/for/etc. statements?

Answer (score 5):

I do this:

```
if(#{params[:param_to_check_for].blank? ? "true" : "false"})
```

In the above case, the condition is 
`params[:param_to_check_for].blank?`.

It renders the JavaScript as either: `if(false)` or `if(true)`

Comment: Why is true a string, but false a boolean?

Comment: @HunterStevens no good reason... probably just because it worked :) fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but I'd think you could do

```
:javascript
    // do something
- if current_user.role? :client
    ="//do something else"
```

(As in the second example [here](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#ruby_blocks).)

For a very short bit of javascript, you could also try

```
:javascript
    // do something
    #{current_user.role? :client ? "//do something else" : ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've interpolated the Ruby/HAML variable into explicit JS `true` or `false` for JS condition like this:

```
$("#cancel").click( function() {
  if (#{ !!my_flag_variable })
    window.location.href = "./";
  else
    $("#dialog").hide();
} );
```

Answer (score -1):

I've accomplished this via a `= yield :foot_scripts` call in my layout, then then:

```
= if condition
  - content_for :foot_scripts do
    - render :partial => "page_specific_javascript"
```

in my views — that way I can ensure the Javascript is executed exactly where I want it to be in the DOM (AFTER everything else), and maintain it in a separate file, which is vastly cleaner. Getting script out of your view files? GOOD!

Answer (score -3):

That's pretty much right.

The other option is you could put it in a `.js.erb` partial and render that from your haml view.

Then you can just do

```
// do something
<% if condition == true %>
  // do something else
<% end %>
```